# Copy row from one sheet to recent sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I want to simply copy the first row "test" into all following sheets (Sheetxx1, Sheetx23, Sheet231, etc. ) ... (like 100 following sheets with different names).

So I tried this by recording a macro (with relative reference) and then went on the sheet, where I want to have it pasted (like Sheetx231) and then did run the macro. But what it did is it pasted again row "test" into Sheetxx23.

How can I make the macro paste the row test of Sheetxx1 into the recent sheet (I am in and run the macro)?

[image: excel workbook]

```
Sub Macro1() 
    Rows("1:1").Select 
    Selection.Copy 
    Sheets("Sheetxx23").Select 
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not being very clear. Do you want to paste this onto every sheet except the sheet it's copied from? Or is it only some sheets - and if so how do you tell determine what sheets to paste to and what sheets not to?

Comment: Also, why are you complicating your `first row` statement by calling it `test`? Unclear if you mean it will always be the first row or if this is a variable.

Comment: Please also include your attempt (code) and tell what was going wrong and where exactly you got stuck or errors.

Comment: To be clear: I want to copy the first row in sheet1 and paste it into every other sheet in the excel workbook. The Code:                                                                                                               Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheetxx23").Select
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: @Alex Paste in which location of every other sheet? Into the first row of every other sheet? Please clarify. And please add the code you have tried.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please always add code as text formatted as code block.

Comment: Sorry !!! This is the code:     Sub Macro1() ' ' Macro1 Macro ' ' Rows("1:1").Select Selection.Copy Sheets("Sheetxx23").Select ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select ActiveSheet.Paste End Sub –

Comment: Yes, To be clear: I want to copy the first row in sheet1 and paste it into the same place (first row) to every other sheet in the excel workbook.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, as you can see the code gets pretty unreadable in comments. So the good practice is to always add the code to the original question where it can be formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop throuh all worksheets and copy/paste for each worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyFirstRowIntoAllWorksheets()
    Dim SourceWs As Worksheet
    Set SourceWs = ActiveSheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop throuh all sheets
        If Not ws.Name = SourceWs.Name Then 'makes sure source and destination is not the same sheet
            SourceWs.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=ws.Rows(1) 'copy first row
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Edit according comment:

If you need only the worksheets right of the active worksheet to be pasted, replace

```
If Not ws.Name = SourceWs.Name Then
```

with

```
If ws.Index > SourceWs.Index Then
```

Comment: just one more question:  How can I avoid, if I have for instance before Sheet xx1two more sheets (Calendar and another one), that it pastes also into the sheets before? So I would just like to have it pasted into all 100 following sheets after Sheetxx1

Comment: I tried it like this:  
Public Sub CopyFirstRowIntoAllWorksheets()
    Dim SourceWs As Worksheet
    Set SourceWs = ActiveSheet
    Set ExcludeWs = Worksheets("Calendar")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop throuh all sheets
        If Not ws.Name = (SourceWs.Name Or ExcludeWs) Then 'makes sure source and destination is not the same sheet'
            SourceWs.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=ws.Rows(1) 'copy first row
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub